# memory leak using JSONKit when called a second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, memory-leaks

I've read the Apples docs on memory management and feel I understand them but I can't get this to not leak. In this example I have the process running on the main thread to keep it simple. The first time search button is clicked all works fine, no leaks. Second time search is clicked/perfomed everything works find but instruments displays the following leaks:

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
NSCFString,42   < multiple >    1.30 KB CTContacts  jk_cachedObjects
NSCFString,16   < multiple >    464 Bytes   CTContacts  jk_cachedObjects
JKDictionary,7  < multiple >    224 Bytes   CTContacts  jk_object_for_token
Malloc 288 Bytes,7  < multiple >    1.97 KB CTContacts  jk_object_for_token
Malloc 32 Bytes,    0x7859a30   32 Bytes    CTContacts  jk_object_for_token
JKArray,    0x78599f0   32 Bytes    CTContacts  jk_object_for_token
```

it seems to be pointing to this line: (listed as %100)

```
NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [jsonData objectFromJSONDataWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionStrict error:(NSError **)error];
```

I've tried NSDictionary *resultsDictionary =[ [[NSDictionary alloc]init]autorelease]; but with same result.

Below are the two methods involved:

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {    
pickerView.hidden=YES;
searchBar.showsScopeBar=YES;
[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];

[self queryWebService];
}

-(void) queryWebService{

NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myweb.com/json.php?lname=%@&searchType=%@",searchBar.text,currentSearchCategory];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error){
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    //NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);

    NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [jsonData objectFromJSONDataWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionStrict error:(NSError **)error];

    if (resultsDictionary)
    {
        rows = [[resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"contacts"] retain];
        resultsDictionary=nil;
    }
}        
[myTableView reloadData];
}
```

NSArray "rows" is used as the tableView dataSource. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine that `rows` is the cause.  Each time you run through the loop, you add another `retain` to it.  Getting rid of the `retain` should do the trick and get rid of the memory leak.  If for some reason, a `retain` is necessary there, you'll just have to find a place elsewhere to release it and keep your retain count at the proper value

Comment: Duhhh, did I say I had a handle on this memory stuff. Thanks slev, that was it. Don't see how to accept this as the correct answer, I'll check back later and see if option is available.

Comment: Haha, you get the hang of it over time.  So no worries there.  But you're more than welcome

Comment: did you try running the static analysis tool on it? it likely would have caught that.

Comment: I would suggest to retain the rows variable as it could be autoreleased (it's hard to know if the methods that are returning are autoreleased or not in the example) and cause a crash. However before you retain it you need to release the previous data. ie. [rows release]; rows = ..... retain];